# How to Update my column if there value exists in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables, class and student table.

student table contains student_name,class_time and class_id.

class table contains  class_time , class id with IsClassConduct.

I want to update class table'scolumn IsClassConduct  Y if its time and class_id exist in student table

[image]

[image]

and desire result will be as

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please add text data instead of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE ClassTable c
SET c.IsClassConduct = CASE WHEN EXIST ( SELECT 1
                                         FROM StudentTable s
                                         WHERE s.class_id = c.class_id
                                           AND INSTR(s.class_time, c.class_time) > 0 )
                            THEN 'Y'
                            ELSE 'N' 
                            END
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
update classTable set IsClassConduct = 'Y'
where (Class_time,class_id) in (select class_time,class_id from student_talbe);
```

OR You can do it using inner join also.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MERGE:

```
merge into class A using (select class_id,class_time from student)B 
on (A.class_id=B.class_id and instr(B.class_time,A.class_time)>0) 
when matched then update set A.IsClassConduct='Y';
```

You can also use CONTAINS(B.class_time,A.class_time)>0 instead of INSTR, but for that you will have to create INDEX.